# Ehcache with Spring + Jersey

Tags: java, spring, jersey, ehcache, jersey-2.0

I am trying an experiment to try to Cache the JSON response from the Jersey controller / web service to see if it has any impact on performance.

I have the following Jersey rest service.

```
@Component
@Path("/client")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ClientController {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientController.class);

    @Autowired
    IClientService clientService;

    @GET
    @Cacheable(value = "jerseyCache")
    public String getClients() {
        return "Nothing, I'm Sync!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/deferred")
    public DeferredResult<String> getClientsAsync() {
        DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
        deferredResult.setResult("Nothing! But I'm Async!");
        return deferredResult;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/async")
    public void getClientsJAXRSAsync(@Suspended AsyncResponse response) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            response.resume("I am Async too! But I am using @Suspended");
        }).start();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Client getClient(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return new Client();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Client createClient(@Valid Client client) {
        return new Client();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void updateClient(@PathParam("id") Long id, @Valid Client client) {
        return;
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void deleteClient(@PathParam("id")Long id) {
        return;
    }
```

When I call /api/client I get the following stacktrace.

```
15:01:55.681 ERROR DirectJDKLog.log - Servlet.service() for servlet [jerseyServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheResolver.resolveCaches(AbstractCacheResolver.java:78) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:216) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.<init>(CacheAspectSupport.java:568) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getOperationContext(CacheAspectSupport.java:229) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContexts.<init>(CacheAspectSupport.java:511) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:302) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at net.jkratz.agility.web.ClientController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1ad41944.getClients(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RC1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) ~[jersey-server-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144) ~[jersey-server-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161) ~[jersey-server-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205) ~[jersey-server-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99) ~[jersey-server-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) ~[jersey-server-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) ~[jersey-server-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) ~[jersey-server-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308) ~[jersey-server-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) ~[jersey-common-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) ~[jersey-common-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291) ~[jersey-server-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140) ~[jersey-server-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:403) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.18.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:329) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.M1.jar:1.3.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.M1.jar:1.3.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:68) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.M1.jar:1.3.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Here is my CacheConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig implements CachingConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCacheManager(ehCacheManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
    }

    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return new SimpleCacheResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new SimpleCacheErrorHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactoryBean() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        ehCacheManagerFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        ehCacheManagerFactoryBean.setShared(true);
        ehCacheManagerFactoryBean.setCacheManagerName("agilityCacheManager");
        return ehCacheManagerFactoryBean;
    }
```

Finally my ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false"
         monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

    <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        timeToLiveSeconds="0"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="50"
        maxElementsOnDisk="100000"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="300"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        statistics="true">
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="jerseyCache"
       maxElementsInMemory="10000"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="0"
       timeToLiveSeconds="0"
       overflowToDisk="true"
       diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="50"
       maxElementsOnDisk="100000"
       diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="300"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
       statistics="true">
    </cache>

    <cache
        name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false">
    </cache>

    <cache
        name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToLiveSeconds="300">
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

Comment: Having exactly the same issue any update?

Comment: Unfortunately no, we just decided to drop ehcache.

Answer (score 2):

I got similar issue as migrating spring from 3.2.13 to 4.2.1 . It works finally by replace "implements CachingConfigurer" with "extends CachingConfigurerSupport".